# Spring WebSocket stopped working, how to find the reason?

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I cannot understand why sometimes my `spring boot` (version 1.4.1) application based on `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and `spring-boot-starter-websocket` stops working.

Specifically my application provides is meant to provide to the client some real-time events about system status. These events can be both periodical or in response to user input and events are sent by means of the `SimpMessagingTemplate`'s convertAndSend method.

Sometimes all events stops working but I cannot find any evidence in logs: nor exceptions neither BrokerAvailabilityEvents saying that the Broker failed.

I have no idea of how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that `SimpMessagingTemplate`'s convertAndSend method was not called because the thread that was responsible for calling it on behalf of an event was stuck and froze all event notification chain.

Comment: Hi Did you find any solutions for this.

Comment: It was my bad. The thread responsible for calling convertAndSend in order to send the event was in deadlock on a condition. So no issue in `spring-boot-starter-websocket`.

Comment: Ok, Is there any fix for this. We are facing an issue like when in the chat there are 10 users, websocket connection lost, not able to send the chat message, when we checked the server, the server is still alive. Only the solution is restart the server, then the chat will start working.